# How to interpret doc2vec results on previously seen data?

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

I use gensim 4.0.1 and train doc2vec:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
    
sentences = [['hello', 'world'], ['james', 'bond'], ['adam', 'smith']]
documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(sentences)]
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=5, min_count=0, workers=4)
```

```
documents
    [TaggedDocument(words=['hello', 'world'], tags=[0]),
    TaggedDocument(words=['james', 'bond'], tags=[1]),
    TaggedDocument(words=['adam', 'smith'], tags=[2])]
```

```
model.dv[0],model.dv[1],model.dv[2]
        (array([-0.10461631, -0.11958256, -0.1976151 ,  0.1710569 ,  0.0713223 ],
               dtype=float32),
         array([ 0.00526548, -0.19761242, -0.10334401, -0.19437183,  0.04021204],
               dtype=float32),
         array([ 0.05662392,  0.09290017, -0.08597242, -0.06293383, -0.06159503],
               dtype=float32))
```

I expect to get a match on TaggedDocument #1

```
seen = ['james','bond']
```

Surprisingly, that known text (james bond) produces a completely "unseen" vector:

```
new_vector = model.infer_vector(seen)
new_vector
        
        array([-0.07762126,  0.03976333, -0.02985927,  0.07899596, -0.03556045],
              dtype=float32)
```

The *most_similar()* does not point to the expected Tag=1. Moreover, all 3 scores are quite weak implying completely unseen data.

```
model.dv.most_similar_cosmul(positive=[new_vector]) 
[(0, 0.5322251915931702), (2, 0.4972134530544281), (1, 0.46321794390678406)]
```

What is wrong here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Five dimensions is still too many for a toy-sized dataset of just 6 words, 6 unique words, and 3 2-word texts.

None of the `Word2Vec`/`Doc2Vec`/`FastText`-type algorithms works well on tiny amounts of contrived data. They only learn their patterns from many, subtly-contrasting usages of words in varied contexts.

Their real strengths only emerge with vectors that are 50, 100, or hundreds-of-dimensions wide - and training that many dimensions requires a unique vocabulary of (at least) many thousands of words – ideally tens or hundreds of thousands of words – with many usage examples of each. (For a variant like `Doc2Vec`, you'd similarly want many thousands of varied documents.)

You'll see improved correlations with expected results when using sufficient training data.

Comment: Thank you, @gojomo. I tried with vector_size=1,2,3 and don't see much difference. The most_similar() scores are equally likely toward each of the trained docs.

I don't understand why infer_vector() on trained sample (james bond) computes a very(!) different vector from the existing trained vector i.e. model.dv[1]

Comment: I see your multiple posts on [doc2vec inference non-determinism](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/447)

Comment: It's still far too little data for this algorithm to work. It's not at all expected to do anything useful for vector-sizes of 1, 2, or 3 and a mere 6-word corpus. You *might* be able to eke out some vague hints of the algorithm's true usefulness on a corpus of a few hundred docs, of a few hundred words each, with a few thousand unique words, and a model of maybe 20 dimensions that's trained by an extra large number of epochs. (A few Gensim test-cases & intro-demos do this.)

Comment: But, that's still mostly a waste of time, because the algorithm is meant for thousands/tens-of-thousands/millions of Docs, each with at least dozens and preferable hundreds of words or more, and a vocabulary of tens-of-thousands of unique words, each with many contrasting usage examples. (`min_count=0` is almost always a very bad idea.) It needs that bulk & variety from large training data for its process to come up with something useful.

Comment: I tried to work on large corpus (6M short docs) and the result is same. The most_similar cannot find previously seen phrase.

Comment: If I need to work with short docs (phrases) where each unique word has a decisive discriminating power (min_count=0), does it mean (as I read above) doc2vec is not the choice, what might be a recommendation?

Comment: You should post more details about your 6M document case – perhaps in a new question? – with specifics of what the texts are like, how they're preprocessed, how the training is done, etc. It's impossible to know what's going wrong in a real situation with only the details from a toy setup! Also, be clear what you mean by "cannot find previously seen phrase"? (How long is the phrase? Does 'cannot find' mean it's not a result even when re-inferring the exact same list-of-words? Or just that it's not as highly-ranked as some other reasoning wants it to be? Etc.)

Comment: Nothing in the family of Word2Vec-related algorithms can leanr much about a word from only a single example of its use. That's why the default is usually to throw away such rare words entirely - it actually improves the remaining word-vectors to not have such noise. This is especially the case with some PV-DM `Doc2Vec` modes, where a solo word can even behave a bit like a 2nd doc-vector (for its window), diluting the *other* unique doc-vector for that text.

Comment: If you need exact-by-rare-keyword recall of documents, you should use keyword search. The sort of fuzzy comparisons of `Doc2Vec' need many training examples, so are unlikely to help with a word that appears only once in a tens-of-millions-of-words training corpus. If you need them to work, you need to find more training data for any important such words.

Comment: I understand the issue with solo words. Thank you.
I run a few more experiments following tutorial and don't know to explain [most_similar] ranking results. As you'd suggested I go to post another question. Sorry if the answer (insufficient training data) will the same.